IndexError when trying to iterate over list
I just finished the online Harvard CS50P course and for my first project I am trying to develop a program that calculates the y-value of polynomial functions. I know my code is probably terribly optimized and that there is a library that already does what I am doing but it is not really my focus. I am trying to do something that works no matter what.
import math

equation = input("Equation: ").strip().lower().replace(" ", "")
value = input("Value of x: ")

chars = []
exponents = []
mults = []
sums = []
subs = []
divs = []
sqrts = []

result = 0

for char in equation:
    if char == "x":
        char = char.replace("x", value)
        chars.append(char)
    else: 
        chars.append(char)

for op in range(len(chars)):
    if chars[op] == "^":
        exponents.append(1)
    elif chars[op] == "*":
        mults.append(op)
    elif chars[op] == "+":
        sums.append(op)
    elif chars[op] == "-":
        subs.append(op)
    elif chars[op] == "/":
        divs.append(op)
    elif chars[op] == "v":
        sqrts.append(op)
        
for exponent in range(len(exponents)):
    expResult = int(chars[exponents[exponent] - 1]) ** int(chars[exponents[exponent] + 1])
    chars[exponents[exponent] - 1] = expResult
    chars.remove(chars[exponents[exponent]])
    chars.remove(chars[exponents[exponent]])
    exponents.remove(1)
    result += float(expResult)
    
for sqrt in range(len(sqrts)):
    sqrtResult = int(chars[sqrts[sqrt] - 1]) * math.sqrt(int(chars[sqrts[sqrt] + 1]))
    chars[sqrts[sqrt] - 1] = sqrtResult
    chars.remove(chars[sqrts[sqrt]])
    chars.remove(chars[sqrts[sqrt]])
    result += float(sqrtResult)

for mult in range(len(mults)):
    multResult = int(chars[mults[mult] - 1]) * int(chars[mults[mult] + 1])
    chars[mults[mult] - 1] = multResult
    chars.remove(chars[mults[mult]])
    chars.remove(chars[mults[mult]])
    result += float(multResult)
    
for div in range(len(divs)):
    divResult = int(chars[mults[mult] - 1]) * int(chars[mults[mult] + 1])
    chars[divs[div] - 1] = divResult
    chars.remove(chars[divs[div]])
    chars.remove(chars[divs[div]])
    result += float(divResult)
    
print(result)
print(chars)
print(exponents)

I am still in the first steps of developing it. However, whenever I input a function with more than 1 operation, I get IndexError: list index out of range.
So, for example:
Equation: x^3^3
Value of x: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vinisiqueira/graphingCalc/graphingCalc.py", line 38, in <module>
    expResult = int(chars[exponents[exponent] - 1]) ** int(chars[exponents[exponent] + 1])
                          ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

When I change the for loops to iterate just one time, I get:
Equation: 2^3^2
Value of x: 2
8.0
[8, '^', '2']
[1]

So that means that for the first operation, it works, but somehow fails when doing the exact same thing again.
I am very sorry for this code if it is unclear, but any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

You're calling exponents.remove(1) inside that loop, making the exponents list smaller, so it disagrees with the original length from for exponent in range(len(exponents)): loop.

Don't remove items from a list as you're iterating over it.  Bad things happen, just like this.

You need to bear in mind that for a non-empty list of length N the valid range of indexes is -N to N-1

Lets disect here
for exponent in range(len(exponents)):
expResult = int(chars[exponents[exponent] - 1]) ** int(chars[exponents[exponent] + 1])

i want to make it shorter by onesimple substitions
instead of exponent i will write i
and currently we can make it to  ** int(chars[exponents[exponent] + 1]) part so i wont be writing it since it doesnt contribute to our error here.
   for i in range(len(exponents)):
      expResult = int(chars[exponents[i] - 1]) 

"list index out of range" indicates it is highly possible that your exponents[i]-1 value results a bigger value then len(chars)
to test this please run
for exponent in range(len(exponents)):
    print(f" length of char list is  {len(chars)}" )
    print(f" current exponent value is   {exponents[exponent]} ")
    expResult = int(chars[exponents[exponent] - 1]) ** int(chars[exponents[exponent] + 1])

when your current exponent value exceeds the length of char list you can see why your code fails
